# How to connect to Wifi network with no essid or password?

Tags: networking

While scanning for wireless networks I stumbled across a mysterious network with the following output:

```
          Cell 03 - Address: FA:8F:CA:97:7D:D0
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:""
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000041afb595478
                Extra: Last beacon: 1108ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0000
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 050400020000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C1103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601000100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

Now I tried selecting "Connect to a hidden Wifi network" in the Network manager but it wont let me connect without a SSID.

Comment: Since it's hidden by the owner, you need to actually know the name of the ssid and security key (if used).

Comment: `nmcli d wifi connect BSSID` where `BSSID` can be found in `nmcli d wifi list`. It will prompt for a password if there is any.